# unable to allign script at center of page despite several attempts

Tags: html, css, center

I am unable to place my ads at the center of my site `www.ios7.me`

this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ch_client = "verronica";
ch_width = 250;
ch_height = 250;
ch_type = "mpu";
ch_sid = "Chitika Default";
ch_color_site_link = "0000CC";
ch_color_title = "0000CC";
ch_color_border = "FFFFFF";
ch_color_text = "000000";
ch_color_bg = "FFFFFF";
</script>
<script src="http://scripts.chitika.net/eminimalls/amm.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I have tried various attempts like:

```
<div align="center">
script
</div>

<center>
script
</center>

<td allign="center">
script
</td>
```

but all did not go so well Its all just alligned to left.
I have run out of all clues as I am very poor in css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its simple, just assign some hard code WIDTH and apply MARGIN to AUTO to your DIV (which is wrapping your ADs).
For Example:

```
<div style="width:1024px; margin:auto;">
    <!-- Your Ad related code here -->
</div>
```

or simply if you want to get width dynamicaly as soon as your page loads, then do let me know in your comment, i will surely get that done for you :)

All the Best !

Comment: thats cool :) please mark the answer ACCPETED if it was to the point or increase the rating. Else i`m here to guide you more if i can.

Thank You !

Comment: two more reputation and i will do it immediately sir!

Answer (score 2):

The `<center>` element is deprecated - see http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html 
. Use CSS instead so, `<p style="text-align:center;">script</p>`
. Also try `margin: auto;`

If you could show a live example (use something like http://jsfiddle.net/) that would really help as there are various dependancies that CSS relies on to work correctly.

Hope this helps

Comment: hey! I tried that and it did work I was able to align it to center in that tester,however I am not able to align it in my website alone...

Answer (score 1):

i do this it works .... please try and check it

The  element is deprecated - see http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html . Use CSS instead so, script

. Also try margin: auto;

If you could show a live example (use something like http://jsfiddle.net/) that would really help as there are various dependancies that CSS relies on to work correctly.